# Where can I find Rock Band instruments for Wii

Tags: nintendo-wii, rock-band

I've been searching for Rock Band instruments for the Wii and I cant seem to find anything. It seems that they aren't carried in stores any more and they only place i can find them is private sales on Ebay. Can anyone tell me where i can find instruments? Or does anyone know if more instruments will be released?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked on Amazon?  They seem to have plenty of listings for guitars, keyboards, microphones and drums for the Wii.

Comment: I _have_ looked at Amazon, just now, and it's kind of a confusing mess. It appears to be mostly third-party addons and replacements — no obvious "here's the basic stuff".